# GET multiple xml files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to load multiple xml files depending on which button is clicked.

I have attached a snippet of code, I'm really more focused on the if...else if.

Is what I'm trying to do even logical or possible?

Updated Code with Claudio suggestion:

```
    <script src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<script>
/*********** jQuery Accordion Menu ****************/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn_countries, .btn_regions').hide();
    $('.mainbar > ul > span ul').each(function(index, element){
        var count = $(element).find('li').length;
            $(element).closest('span').children('a').append(content);
                });

    $('.mainbar > ul > span > a').click(function() {
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
    $('.mainbar span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('span').addClass('active'); 
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
             $(this).closest('span').removeClass('active');
             checkElement.slideUp('normal');
             }
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
             $('.mainbar ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
             checkElement.slideDown('normal');
             }
        if($(this).closest('span').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
        });


/*********** jQuery Accordion Menu End****************/

/*********** jQuery load XML ****************/
function xmlFunction( xmlUrl ) {
    $.get( xmlUrl, function ( d ) {
        $( 'body' ).append( '<dl />' );
        $( d ).find( 'company' ).each( function () {

            var $company = $( this ),
                name = $company.attr( "name" ),
                certification = $company.find( 'certification' ).text(),
                employee = $company.find( 'employee' ).text(),
                quote = $company.find( 'quote' ).text(),
                industry = $company.find( 'industry' ).text(),
                signature = $company.find( 'signature' ).text(),
                title = $company.find( 'title' ).text(),
                url = $company.find( 'url' ).text(),
                imageurl = $company.attr( 'imageurl' ),
                html = '';

            html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
            html += '<div class="container">';
            html += '<div class="content">';
            html += '<div class="maincontent">';
            html += '<div class="logoblock">';
            html += '<img class="companyLogo" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" />';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="contentblock">';
            html += '<h1 class="name">' + name + '</h1>';
            html += '<h2 class="certification">' + certification + '</h2>';
            html += '<p class="employee">' + employee + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="industry"> ' + industry + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="quote"> ' + quote + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="signature"> ' + signature + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="title"> ' + title + '</p>';
            html += '<a class="url"> ' + url + '</a>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</dd>';

            $('#global').append( $( html ));
        });
        //show after appending all
        $( '#global' ).show();
    });
}

//when dom is ready
    //listener for click on all our buttons
    $( 'button.someCommonClass' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $this = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();
        //using return after calling our function, so we don't need to care with so many 'else if'
        //easier to read IMO
        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_globalImg' ) ) {
            xmlFunction( 'inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_regionalImg' ) ) {
            xmlFunction( 'inc/Regional_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_countriesImg' ) ) {
            xmlFunction( 'inc/Countries_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
    });
});
/*********** jQuery load XML End****************/
</script>

<body>


<div class="mainbar">
  <ul class="btn_container">
   <span><a href='#' class="btn_globalImg"></a></span>
   <span><a href='#' class="btn_regionalImg"></a>
     <ul class="btn_regions">
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_africaImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_asiaImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_eurImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_latinImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_northImg"></a></li>
      </ul>
   </span>
   <span><a href='#' class="btn_countriesImg"><span></span></a>
     <ul class="btn_countries">
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_africaImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_asiaImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_eurImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_latinImg"></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="btn_northImg"></a></li>
     </ul>
   </span>
</ul>

<div id="global">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you are avoiding the block of the `function` in the `.get` right? Can you try to make it more clear...

Comment: I would like it to still use the function block(d), so that it will still use the correct xml elements I'll attach the rest of the code.

Comment: First things first. You are making $(this) inside document ready. Therefore it's not the button are clicking that will be checked with has class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have something near this as html:

```
<div id="global">My global div</div>
<button class="someCommonClass btn_countriesImg">My btn_countriesImg</button>
<button class="someCommonClass btn_regionalImg">My btn_regionalImg</button>
<button class="someCommonClass btn_globalImg">My btn_globalImg</button>
```

I would do something like this (refer to the comments):

```
//Since you are doing the same thing for all, let's make it a reusable function
function myAwesomeFunction( xmlUrl ) {

    $.get( xmlUrl, function ( d ) {

        //hiding here
        $( '#global' ).hide();

        $( 'body' ).append( '<dl />' );

        $( d ).find( 'company' ).each( function () {

            //no need of all var var var..
            //declaring all at once into one var - that's called 'var lifting'
            var $company = $( this ),
                name = $company.attr( "name" ),
                certification = $company.find( 'certification' ).text(),
                employee = $company.find( 'employee' ).text(),
                quote = $company.find( 'quote' ).text(),
                industry = $company.find( 'industry' ).text(),
                signature = $company.find( 'signature' ).text(),
                title = $company.find( 'title' ).text(),
                url = $company.find( 'url' ).text(),
                imageurl = $company.attr( 'imageurl' ),
                html = '';

            html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
            html += '<div class="container">';
            html += '<div class="content">';
            html += '<div class="maincontent">';
            html += '<div class="logoblock">';
            html += '<img class="companyLogo" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" />';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="contentblock">';
            html += '<h1 class="name">' + name + '</h1>';
            html += '<h2 class="certification">' + certification + '</h2>';
            html += '<p class="employee">' + employee + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="industry"> ' + industry + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="quote"> ' + quote + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="signature"> ' + signature + '</p>';
            html += '<p class="title"> ' + title + '</p>';
            html += '<a class="url"> ' + url + '</a>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</dd>';

            $( '#global' ).append( $( html ) );
            //NOTE: I would prefer using document fragment here and append once at the end
            //Has lot better performance and less browser repaint/reflow.
            //But I'll let that one for you to search and learn
        } );

        //show after appending all
        $( '#global' ).show();
    } );
}

//when dom is ready
$( document ).ready( function () {

    //listener for click on all our buttons
    $( 'button.someCommonClass' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var $this = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();

        //using return after calling our function, so we don't need to care with so many 'else if'
        //easier to read IMO

        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_globalImg' ) ) {
            myAwesomeFunction( 'inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_regionalImg' ) ) {
            myAwesomeFunction( 'inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
        if ( $this.hasClass( 'btn_countriesImg' ) ) {
            myAwesomeFunction( 'inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml' );
            return;
        }
    } );
} );
```

If the comment didn't explained enough, let me know :-)

Comment: Thank you Raphae for your example. but, one question maybe dumb but xmlurl is that for the file path?

Comment: @CG-webdev Yes. In your example it's the same url `inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml` for all but i presumed you would get different xml from each button. So you call `myAwesomeFunction( 'inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml' );` with what xml to get.

Comment: Still having issues, So I'm going to update the code to what you suggested. For some reason it's not pulling in the xml, no errors in the console.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) for your scenario

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.hasClass('btn_globalImg')) {
    $.get('inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml', function(d){ ... });
} else if ($this.hasClass('btn_regionalImg')) {
    $.get('inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml', function(d){ ... });
} else if ($this.hasClass('btn_countriesImg')) {
    $.get('inc/Global_BestEmployers.xml', function(d){ ... });
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a shot. I'm getting a syntax error, but it might be something else with my code.

Comment: Syntax error is likely that `} else if ($this.hasClass('btn_regionalImg') {` should be `} else if ($this.hasClass('btn_regionalImg')) {` <- Extra )

Comment: Tried that, still getting an error which is- SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

} else if ($this.hasClass('btn_regionalImg')) {

Comment: @CG-webdev: I had a typo (missed `)`), please copy the code again

Comment: Made the change, I'm still getting that same syntax error. so I'm sure its something else in my script that is causing this. I'll keep debugging and keep everyone posted